# Cast fails using overloaded = operator in Solaris 11 DeveloperStudio12.6

Tags: c++, casting, operator-overloading, solaris, xerces-c

Piece of code compiles fine in Solaris 10 but fails in Solaris 11 DeveloperStudio 12.6.

```
Error: Cannot cast from DOM_Node to const DOM_XMLDecl&.

Code : xml->root_node = (const DOM_XMLDecl&)(xml->doc.getFirstChild());
```

If I change the code to (stupid though):

```
xml->root_node = (xml->doc.getFirstChild());

Error: Cannot assign DOM_Node to DOM_XMLDecl without "DOM_XMLDecl::operator=(const DOM_XMLDecl&)";.
```

From the library :

```
DOM_XMLDecl & operator = (const DOM_XMLDecl &other);
   /**
      * Assignment operator.  This overloaded variant is provided for
      *   the sole purpose of setting a DOM_Node reference variable to
      *   zero.  Nulling out a reference variable in this way will decrement
      *   the reference count on the underlying Node object that the variable
      *   formerly referenced.  This effect is normally obtained when reference
      *   variable goes out of scope, but zeroing them can be useful for
      *   global instances, or for local instances that will remain in scope
      *   for an extended time,  when the storage belonging to the underlying
      *   node needs to be reclaimed.
      *
      * @param val.  Only a value of 0, or null, is allowed.
      */
```

This code compiles fine in Solaris 10 SunStudio, however fails in Solaris on x86, Studio 12.6 Sun C++ 5.15 SunOS_i386

Oracle in its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E60778_01/pdf/E60746.pdf) says to take off CONST correctness by using -W0 option, does not work for me

My compilation flags are:

```
CC  -mt -xtarget=native -m32  -filt=%none -W0 -xconstcheck=false -g2 -verbose=template -library=iostream -g  -O -DNDEBUG  -c
```

Comment: First, upgrade to DeveloperStudio 12.6.  And if you have an Oracle support contract then apply all patches - including operating system patches.

Comment: It is on 12.6 indeed, and I got in touch with the oracle support few hours back.

Answer (score 0):

This got resolved by modifying the code:

```
xml->root_node =(const DOM_XMLDecl&)(xml->doc.getFirstChild());
```

replaced by:

```
xml->root_node =(const DOM_XMLDecl&) ( *new DOM_Node(xml->doc.getFirstChild()));
```